# cannot display current position on google map v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an android app where a map is displayed with markers dispayed on it. I try to read and display each time my current location using WI-FI/3G/GPS on my mobile android device. The problem i have is that I cannot see the tittle printed and the snippet on my map.
my code is the following.

private void setUpMap() {

```
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));


    // Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Enable / Disable my location button
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

    // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);


    // Get Current Location
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);


    // set map type
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);   // MAP_TYPE_HYBRID

         // Get latitude of the current location
         double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

         // Get longitude of the current location
         double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

         // Create a LatLng object for the current location
         LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

         // Show the current location in Google Map
         mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

         // Zoom in the Google Map
         mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
         mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("I am here!").snippet("success located"));

     }

}
```

Based on the above code of my Maps Activity.java file, i never see the tittle " I am here" because of error null pointer exception for:

double latitude = location.getLatitude();

How can I resolve this issue?

I tried the following yesterday for testing purposes:

// Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map

```
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Enable / Disable my location button
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

    // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);


    // Get Current Location
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);


    // set map type
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);   // MAP_TYPE_HYBRID

     if(myLocation != null) {
         // Get latitude of the current location
         double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

         // Get longitude of the current location
         double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

         // Create a LatLng object for the current location
         LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

         // Show the current location in Google Map
         mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

         // Zoom in the Google Map
         mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
         mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("I am here!").snippet("Consider yourself located"));
                        } //case myLocation not null
                             else { //do nothing
                                                 }
     }

}
```

In tried to open my api at least 10 times after connecting to 3 different places with wi-fi connection. 90% of the times I opened my api I saw my correct current position in a blue color circle. 10% of the times i opened my api I saw a red marker displaying the message "I am here!"(usually when I disable and then enable position settings on my mobile) together with the blue color circle...This means that most of the times I tried to get location the provider (network: wi-fi) failed? Is this a provider problem...?

In the past I developed another project web interface based with javascript, CSS, html code. I used getCurrentLocation-javascript which 100% displayed the correct current location (10 different places I tried in a single day and all my current Locations I got where correct). Is javascript get current position functionality more reliable than java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience, sometimes it takes time to receive your first location and causes the nullpointerexception. It's pretty common. I have been looking around for a bit in the docs of Android SDK and came across the `LocationListener`. According to the docs, it obtains your location when it meets your given parameters in the method.

First of all develop two new methods in your `Activity` and initialize locationManager outside your `setupMap()` method.. and add a new variable. (Make sure to remove 'LocationManager' locationManager in `setupMap()` method.)

```
LocationManager locationManager;

boolean gotLocation = false;

public boolean validLatLng(double lat, double lng) {
    if(lat != null && lng != null) {
        this.gotLocation = true;
        return true;
    } else return false;
}

public boolean haveLocation() { return this.gotLocation; }
```

The method is pretty straight forward and doesn't require a further explanation.

Let's create a new LocationListener for you..

```
LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Do what you need to do.
    }
}
```

As you can see, we're not giving any parameters in the constructor of `LocationListener` as it doesn't have a constructor which require some and haven't anything new in the `onLocationChanged()` method

For example, you wish to obtain the first location from the point the Activity runs which is okay. Let's now use our new methods from your Map Activity into our `onLocationChanged()` method of `mLocationListener`.

```
LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(!haveLocation() && validLatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()) {
            Log.i("mLocationListener", "Got a location!");

            // Stops the new update requests.
            locationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);

            // Get latitude of the current location
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();

            // Get longitude of the current location
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();

            // Create a LatLng object for the current location
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            // Show the current location in Google Map
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

            // Zoom in the Google Map
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("I am here!").snippet("success located"));

        }
    }
}
```

`onLocationChanged()` now checks whether it already has a location or not, if not that's great and proceeds with our next requirement to push it through the if-statement. When `validLatLng()` succeeds and returns true, it enters the if-statement, enters a new string in the LogCat and disables the `LocationManager` from further updates and copy pasted some of your code into `onLocationChanged()` method.

Now we've got that all setup, let's add new stuff/modify your `setupMap()` method.

```
private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));

    // Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Enable / Disable my location button
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

    // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    // set map type
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);   // MAP_TYPE_HYBRID

    // Start new code by kevto.
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0.0f, mLocationListener); // (String) provider, time in milliseconds when to check for an update, distance to change in coordinates to request an update, LocationListener.
    // End new code by kevto
}
```

---

Result, it checks your location when it receives updates and if there's a valid location, it will stop the app from checking your location over and over again and adds the markers to your map.

I haven't tested it myself yet and could have made some typos but it's supposed to work according to the docs of Android.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is well explained and well documented helping me to understand the code functionality! I will try your proposed solution.

Comment: Code changes (initialize double lat,lng = 0; and check if(lat != 0.0 && lng != 0.0) since doubles are primitive types in Java and can’t be null.

Comment: Ahh, of course. Thanks for mentioning. Wasn't really thinking about  it when I wrote this :) !

Comment: Successful compilation and run the api. I do not see "I am here!" and "success located" on blue circle marker (wi-fi,GPS enabled).Behavior is like displaying last known location.In which case am I going to see this message?? In case I connect my mobile to new location (different network provider?)..?

Comment: Do you see "Got a location!" in your logcat?

Comment: Unfortunately I get in Logcat: "Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings". Message displayed on emulator "Google play services stopped!". I have downloaded and installed to emulator the google_play_service apk for android 5.0+ (emulator also is Nexus_4_API_21 with andorid 5). The emulator does not load my map at all. I install app-debug.apk each time on my mobile android device. Is there any other way to check this?

Comment: You can connect your smartphone with your computer and debug straight away from android studio by selecting your smartphone as device to debug your app with.

Comment: The only case i see "Got a Location" is when i enable only GPS on my mobile. In this case i see a)GPS marker with circle in blue color moving while i move and b)red marker with message "I am here!" which remains constant-not moving.. Instead with wi-fi just display circle with blue color. Why i see this behaviour?? Besides i cannot understand the meaning of "if(!haveLocation().. Is it false when mobile provider wifi,GPS checks old position stored memory with new one and if they are different considers not having location??

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your myLocation variable prior to calling a method on it.  I can and will be null in some cases.

So just check to see if it is null, if so return from the function and call it again later, eventually it will be vaild and then you can get the lat and lon and add the marker.  This can happen when you first start the app and you are using gps for the provider and it has not yet acquired a fix.  If this is called from something triggered by a location change, then all you need to do is ignore the cases were the returned value is null, since this method will be called again once a location is available.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29

> public Location getLastKnownLocation (String provider) Added in API
>   level 1
>
> Returns a Location indicating the data from the last known location
>   fix obtained from the given provider.
>
> This can be done without starting the provider. Note that this
>   location could be out-of-date, for example if the device was turned
>   off and moved to another location.
>
> If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned. Parameters
>   provider  the name of the provider Returns
>
> ```
> the last known location for the provider, or null
> ```

Comment: I would love to understand why this answer was down voted (so I can improve it)